# What texts/books deal with Hindu demonology?

Tags: resource, rakshasa

I have studied Western demonology over the past two years. I would like to study it now from a Hindu perspective. So can anybody recommend me books/texts regarding it?

Comment: Some seek for such texts in Atharva Veda I think.